# SSRS SUM IIF Returning 0 at higher group level if 0 is in calculation

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a report which aggregates data from a detail report.  Basically, the Area of a building.  Those are grouped into two categories, top, and bottom.

For the bottom group, if a parameter is met, they are included in the sum.

For the top group, it does the same thing, just groups at a higher level.

There are a few grouped in the bottom group which sum is 0, which is fine, but the issue is the top level then returns a 0 as well for some reason, instead of sum of the rest of the values.

The expression is =iif(Fields!Included.Value = 1,sum(Fields!Area.Value),0)

I can't figure out why it works in all but two of the top groups.

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced a parenthesis. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the IIF is only being evaluated for the first record and not each record.

I think it will work as you expect if you put the SUM outside of the IIF:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Included.Value = 1, Fields!Area.Value, 0))
```

This way it evaluates the Included value for each record and then SUMs the various Area values and zeroes.

Comment: I tried the suggestion, but this is the result: The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox97.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.